# generate heap dump reduces dramatically after performing manual GC

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, heap-dump

this is my first post in stack overflow forum. we are recently experiencing some Java OOME issues and using jvisualvm, yourkit and eclipse mat tools able to idenify and fix some issues...

one behavior observed during analysis is that when we create a heapdump manually using jconsole or jvisualvm, the used heap size in jvm reduces dramatically (from 1.3 GB to 200 MB) after generating the heapdump.
can some one please advise on this behavior? this is a boon in disguise since whenever i see the used heapsize is >1.5GB, i perform a manaul GC and the system is back to lower used heapsize numbers resulting in no jvm restarts.

let me know for any additional details

thanks
Guru

Answer (score 1):

when you use JConsole to create the dump file, there are 2 parameters: The first one is the file name to generate (complete path) and the second one (true by default) indicates if you want to perform a gc before taking the dump. Set it to false if you don't want a full gc before dumping

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I found it while asking a new question of my own, so I figured I'd answer it.

When you generate a heap dump, the JVM performs a System.gc() operation before it generates the heap dump, which is collecting non-referenced objects and effectively reducing your heap utilization.  I am actually looking for a way to disable that System GC so I can inspect the garbage objects that are churning in my JVM.